# Function parameter separator in Perl?

Tags: perl

Function parameters are usually separated by comma(`,`), but seems also by space in some cases, like `print FILEHANDLE 'string'`. Why are both of such separators necessary?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`print` is special builtin Perl function with special syntax rules. [Documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) lists four possible invocations:

```
print FILEHANDLE LIST
print FILEHANDLE
print LIST
print
```

So while in general function arguments are separated by comma (`,`), this is an exception that disambiguates print destination from contents to be printed. Another function that exhibit this behavior is [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Other feature that shares this syntax is called ["Indirect Object Notation"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Invoking-Class-Methods). The expression in form:

```
function object arg1, arg2, … angn
#              ^- no comma here
```

Is equivalent to:

```
object->function(arg1, arg2, … argn)
```

So that following statement pairs are equivalent:

```
$foo = new Bar;
$foo = Bar->new;
```

The Indirect Object Notation has [several problems](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/08/the-problems-with-indirect-object-notation.html) and generally should be avoided, save for few well-known idioms such as `print F "something"`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is wrong. `print` is an operator with custom parsing rules. `print HANDLE LIST` is not an indirect method call. It will disregard HANDLE's class. You can verify this using `perl -MScalar::Util=blessed -E'sub IO::File::print { die } say blessed(*STDOUT{IO}); print STDOUT "foo\n"; STDOUT->print("foo\n");'`

Answer (score 3):

In that example, because `print` takes a list of arguments and has a default. So you need to tell the difference between printing a scalar, and printing *to* a filehandle.

The interpreter can tell the difference between:

```
print $fh "some scalar text";
print $bar, "set to a value ","\n";
print $fh;
print $bar;
```

But this is rather a special case - most functions don't work like that. I normally suggest for print, that surrounding the filehandle arg in braces differentiates.

You can look at prototypes as a way to get perl to do things with parameters, but I'd also normally suggest that makes for less clear code

Comment: There is an extra twist. In the example above the third and forth line would print $fh and $bar to the currently selected filehandle. On the other hand "print FH" would print $_ to the real filehandle FH.

Comment: It can .  my $fh = *STDOUT;  print $fh, "one"; is not the same as     my $fh = *STDOUT;
    print $fh "one";